# CASE .. WHEN expression in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the table with 1 column and has following data

```
Status
a1
i
t
a2
a3
```

I want to display the following result in my select query

```
Status| STATUSTEXT
a1    | Active
i     | Inactive
t     | Terminated
a2    | Active
a3    | Active
```

One way I could think was using a Switch When expression in select query

```
SELECT
status,
CASE status 
WHEN 'a1' THEN 'Active'
WHEN 'a2' THEN 'Active'
WHEN 'a3' THEN 'Active'
WHEN 'i' THEN 'Inactive'
WHEN 't' THEN 'Terminated'
END AS StatusText
FROM stage.tst
```

Is there any other way of doing this where I don't need to write ***When expression 3 times for Active Status***  and the entire active status can be checked in one single expression?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You could use an `IN` clause

Something like

```
SELECT
  status,
  CASE
    WHEN STATUS IN('a1','a2','a3')
    THEN 'Active'
    WHEN STATUS = 'i'
    THEN 'Inactive'
    WHEN STATUS = 't'
    THEN 'Terminated'
  END AS STATUSTEXT
FROM
  STATUS
```

Have a look at this demo

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94578/2/0)

Comment: If I may, I suggest explicitly adding ELSE 'UNKNOWN - PLEASE CALL US' or some other such flag.  In larger data systems with many users, sometimes new values will creep into the data and it can be helpful to urge users to notice and contact you.  I believe without this, the "STATUSTEXT" field will just be blank, which generates fewer user comments.  +1 to Adriaan for the nice indenting, too.

Comment: Good point by noogrub. I would add `ELSE status` before `END` so if a new status does creep in you get the base status value rather than a null for `STATUSTEXT`. I would not default to `ELSE 'active'` in case a new inactive or terminated status is introduced by others. Defaulting to 'active' is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 19):

You can rewrite it to use the ELSE condition of a  [`CASE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php):

```
SELECT status,
       CASE status
         WHEN 'i' THEN 'Inactive'
         WHEN 't' THEN 'Terminated'
         ELSE 'Active'
       END AS StatusText
FROM   stage.tst
```

Answer (score 19):

Of course...

```
select case substr(status,1,1) -- you're only interested in the first character.
            when 'a' then 'Active'
            when 'i' then 'Inactive'
            when 't' then 'Terminated'
       end as statustext
  from stage.tst
```

However, there's a few worrying things about this schema. Firstly if you have a column that means something, appending a number onto the end it not necessarily the best way to go. Also, depending on the number of status' you have you might want to consider turning this column into a foreign key to a separate table.

---

Based on your comment you definitely want to turn this into a foreign key. For instance

```
create table statuses ( -- Not a good table name :-)
    status varchar2(10)
  , description varchar2(10)
  , constraint pk_statuses primary key (status)
    )

create table tst (
    id number
  , status varchar2(10)
  , constraint pk_tst primary key (id)
  , constraint fk_tst foreign key (status) references statuses (status)
    )
```

Your query then becomes

```
select a.status, b.description
  from tst a
  left outer join statuses b
    on a.status = b.status
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39f8e/2) to demonstrate.

Comment: I have provided a general example for my cause. However I am not interested in just the first character.

Comment: +1 especially for mentioning the worrying things about this schema.

Answer (score 7):

It will be easier to do using **decode**.

```
SELECT
  status,
    decode ( status, 'a1','Active',
                     'a2','Active',
                     'a3','Active',
                     'i','Inactive',
                     't','Terminated',
                     'Default')STATUSTEXT
FROM STATUS
```

Answer (score 2):

Since web search for `Oracle case` tops to that link, I add here for case **statement**, though not answer to the question asked about case **expression**:

```
CASE
   WHEN grade = 'A' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Excellent');
   WHEN grade = 'B' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Very Good');
   WHEN grade = 'C' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Good');
   WHEN grade = 'D' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Fair');
   WHEN grade = 'F' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Poor');
   ELSE dbms_output.put_line('No such grade');
END CASE;
```

or other variant:

```
CASE grade
   WHEN 'A' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Excellent');
   WHEN 'B' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Very Good');
   WHEN 'C' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Good');
   WHEN 'D' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Fair');
   WHEN 'F' THEN dbms_output.put_line('Poor');
   ELSE dbms_output.put_line('No such grade');
END CASE;
```

Per Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm

Comment: seems to be not-supported to write multiples in `when` 2nd variant like `case grade when 1,2 then`. if you know otherwise, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Following syntax would work :

```
....
where x.p_NBR =to_number(substr(y.k_str,11,5))
and x.q_nbr = 
 (case 
 when instr(substr(y.m_str,11,9),'_') = 6   then  to_number(substr(y.m_str,11,5))
 when instr(substr(y.m_str,11,9),'_') = 0   then  to_number(substr(y.m_str,11,9))
  else 
       1
  end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only check the first character of the status. For this you use substring function.

substr(status, 1,1)

In your case past.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECODE(SUBSTR(STATUS,1,1),'a','Active','i','Inactive','t','Terminated','N/A')
```