# Using a simple case statement in a procedure

Tags: plsql, case, procedure

As I was updating tables, I though to myself that my way is very cumbersome so I though of using a case statement. Although I would like to use it in a simple procedure, though thats where my problem occur! Cant seem to get it right.

**Help is greatly appreciated.**

**My table:**

```
 drop table tbh;
 CREATE TABLE tbh ( a NUMBER, b number, c varchar2(3));
 INSERT INTO tbh VALUES( 1, '0','');
 INSERT INTO tbh VALUES( 2, '2','');
 INSERT INTO tbh VALUES( 3, '7','');
```

**My Case:**

```
UPDATE tbh
SET c =
CASE WHEN a > b THEN 'W'
WHEN a < b THEN 'L'
WHEN a = b THEN 'D'
END ;
```

**What I tried:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WIN (IN P_WT VARCHAR2(3))
BEGIN
CASE P_WT
WHEN a > b THEN
UPDATE tbh SET c = 'W';
WHEN a < b THEN
UPDATE tbh SET c = 'L';
WHEN a = b THEN
UPDATE tbh SET c = 'D';
END CASE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply use pure sql:

```
UPDATE tbh
SET c = 'W'
where a > b 

UPDATE tbh
SET c = 'L'
where a < b 

UPDATE tbh
SET c = 'D'
where a = b
```

Update: `Thanks to @Wolf P. for the comment`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE detectMatchResult as
BEGIN
UPDATE tbh
    SET c = 'W' -- Win
    where a > b ;

    UPDATE tbh
    SET c = 'L' -- Lose
    where a < b ;

    UPDATE tbh
    SET c = 'D' -- Draw
    where a = b; 
Commit;
END;
```

I don't think that usage of oracle switch case is a well-advised solution for your question.
For some simple sample you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650875/case-when-expression-in-oracle-sql) or  [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

Comment: Yes I can, but I would really like to try via a procedure. As do I, my syntax is probably way off, thats why I'm asking for help!

Comment: @Mohsen Heydari: As I understand the procedure, it has the meaning to detect a "win" status *Win*, *Lose*, *Draw*. So, maybe, you can improve your answer by removing the didn't-understand comment and adding the original procedure name. (I'll keep my +1 ready)

Comment: Thanks 4 the smart comment pal ;)