# Is it possible to use CASE with ANY() in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, conditional-statements

Is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do in the below SQL query?
I want to check if the item name matches any of the given list.

```
select
  case item_name
    when any ('PEN', 'PENCIL', 'PAPER', 'ERASER') then 'STATIONARY'
    else 'OTHER'
  end is_stationary
from items;
```

I tried this query, and seems it is not possible. The error message is,

```
 ORA-00936: missing expression
 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
 Error at Line: 29 Column: 10
```

Is there any other workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
select
  case when item_name IN ('PEN', 'PENCIL', 'PAPER', 'ERASER') then 'STATIONARY'
    else 'OTHER'
  end is_stationary
from items;
```

[**CASE ..  IN ..  REFERENCE LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650875/case-when-expression-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: It does not work. Missing keyword error this time. (`ORA-00905: missing keyword`)

Comment: This should work. There must be something else which results in this error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I had missed the `then 'STATIONARY'` part. It works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: and for the record, it is spelled 'stationery' in this case :)

Answer (score 5):

@bvr's answer is by far the most common way to solve this problem.  But it looks like you were very close to correctly using an alternative syntax, the 
[group comparison condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions002.htm#sthref1923).

```
select
  case
    when item_name = any ('PEN', 'PENCIL', 'PAPER', 'ERASER') then 'STATIONARY'
    else 'OTHER'
  end is_stationary
from items;
```