# Using IF statements in Oracle when trying to return data

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I return data out of IF statements? I have a IF statement which is meant to return a different result dependent of the result of that statement.

```
IF :Value = 1 THEN
SELECT Name FROM TABLE_A
ELSEIF :Value = 2 THEN
SELECT Name FROM TABLE_B
ELSEIF :Value = 3 THEN
SELECT Name FROM TABLE_C
```

but this doesn't work. It expects an INTO statement in those selects. I suspect this is because Oracle can't return out of a block?

Is there a quicker way to return those select statements without creating table variables to store the data or messing around with functions?

Comment: `IF` is plsql statement, `select * ....` is sql. They are different languages. There is a way to run sql statements inside plsql using `execute immediate`. But then again, without knowing the context you are trying to implement or what you are trying to achieve, it is very hard to suggest anything

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by plain SQL:

```
SELECT
  ':Value' user_input,
  CASE
    WHEN   ':Value'  IN('a1','a2','a3')
    THEN (select name from table_a)
    WHEN   ':Value'  = 'i'
    THEN (select name from table_b)
  END AS output
FROM
  dual
```

([good info about case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650875/case-when-expression-in-oracle-sql))

Comment: Thanks, would this work if the elect is going to return more than 1 column?

Comment: Yes, add , `,` after `as output`  and you can use more columns.

Comment: @Ice Ah ok but a seperate case statement is required each time.

Comment: Nope, it is possible to `select case ... end, emp_address from emps`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one result in your cases, then you may opt to an intelligent `UNION`:

```
  SELECT t1_Col_1, t1_Col_2,'&VALUE' from TABLE_1
   WHERE '&VALUE' = '1'
UNION ALL
  SELECT t2_Col_1, t2_Col_2,'&VALUE' from TABLE_2
   WHERE '&VALUE' = '2'
```

In this solution, types and  number of `tx_Coln` must be the same.

Comment: you need to write multiple answers,  you can just add an header in the same answer and provide an alternative